# VPN connection problems since updating to Monterey

Tags: vpn, macos-monterey

I updated my macOS to Monterey and since this update, I have trouble with VPN connection to my company. I can connect to my company VPN but can not use it afterwards. No computer or internet is reachable.

After searching the Internet, I found a suggestions, that `iCloud Private Relay` might interfere with the VPN connection.
All the manuals, pointing me to `Settings -> iCould -> uncheck Private Relay` does not work for, since there is no checkbox in front of the `Private Relay` button and I can not activate nor deactivate it. Instead, there is an `update` button behind it, where I get forwarded to upgrade my iCloud plan, which I do not want.

After looking for some theory behind `Private Relay`, I recognised a setting in my networks called `Limit IP Address Tracking`. After unchecking this checkbox, I could connect and use my VPN as usual.

The PROBLEM I now have is, this only works for wifi but not for my ethernet connection. And my wifi at home office is pretty bad and it is disconnecting all the time.

I restarted everything and tried it several times. It is reproducible for the ethernet connection via Thunderbolt (it never works independent of the `Limit IP Address Tracking` checkbox. For wifi it works with unchecked `Limit IP Address Tracking` setting.

My workaround is at the moment, I disconnect ethernet, I wait for a wifi connection, connect VPN, connect ethernet, disconnect wifi...
This works then some minutes to hours.

Any suggestions on why this is not working as expected for thunderbolt connection? Everything was working fine with previous OS.

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437553/vpn-connection-problems-since-updating-to-monterey